# Jackson unable to deserialize the fields with hyphen

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

In the below code resultant orderObj doesn't have contract-id, order-number details.  It is only deserialized the fields with hyphens.  As per my knowledge @jsonproperty should map.

Please help to get all the fields in my result orderObj.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6791737023394030929L;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("contract-id")
    private String contractId;

    @JsonProperty("order-number")
    private String orderNumber;
}


final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory()));
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL, true);

Response response = orderServiceTarget.queryParam("contract-id",contractId).request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).headers(headersMap).get();
final String serverResponseStr = response.readEntity(String.class);
Order  orderObj = objectMapper.readValue(serverResponseStr, Order.class);
```

Result object is: it is missing the other fields,

```
{
    "id": "7FABA1724B8F15306447852233",
}
```

Here is the server response:

```
{
    "id": "7FABA1724B8F15306447852233",
    "contract-id": "42BAD9AAA5231BD",
    "order-number": "ADD",
    "market-segment": "COM",
}
```

Comment: Added server response in the post.

Comment: I notice you're using `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` but not JAXB annotations e.g. `@XmlElement` - is that intentional?

Comment: Awesome. you pointed correctly. I am working two different usecases and used the same code here too. It worked.  Please comment in answer section will accept it.

Comment: Though i got response but after mapper.readValue()  the response object fields has hyphen  eg:   "order-number": "ADD",   "market-segment": "COM", .  It is supposed to be converted to camelcase since it is mapped with jsonproperty in Order.java.  am i missing anything?

Comment: @Kiran I think that's expected behavior. The name specified by `@JsonProperty` is the intended field name for the JSON format. If you'd like camelcase JSON field names, you could change the names in `@JsonProperty` or just remove them and Jackson will use the Java field name by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it looks like your `ObjectMapper` is configured to use `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`, which will look for e.g. `@XmlElement` instead of `@JsonProperty`. The `id` field still works since its field name matches between JSON and Java.

You should be able to fix the issue by simply removing this line:

```
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory()));
```